# Guest VM on XenServer unable to reach network

Tags: networking, xenserver

We have set up a XenServer, and trying to set-up a CentOS 6 guest VM.

The installation went fine (using RHEL 6 template), but I'm unable to properly configure the network. The guest VM is able to ping the host machine, but unable to ping any outside machines or gateway.

The network settings look just fine - same subnet range and valid IP.

Any idea what else I can check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just moved the machines to second NIC - and magically they started seeing the network.

Quite strange but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the most likely culprit is the firewall on the host.  This can be confirmed by running

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Which will stop the firewall.  Then try your ping tests.  Use

```
/etc/init.d/iptables start
```

To bring it back up again once confirmed.

Comment: Tried this, still no luck. I see peth0 interface missing on XenServer host (it required on open-source Xen), this be the problem?

Comment: The name of the interface isn't too important, but you do need a bridge of some kind if they are to exist on the same network.  Can you post the vif line from the config file?

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure where the config files located on XenServer, any idea where to look for them?